# Will a recent change to me being a Canadian PR make any difference to me getting a visa?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I'm a French Citizen with a French passport. I need to apply for a B2 visa for the USA as I visited a country that makes me ineligible for an ESTA / VWP. I only want to go on vacation for a week or so occasionally, I don't need the 6 month validity etc.

I've travelled a lot, and I have been to the us before twice (once was a 24 layover and the other was a 2 week vacation - on a previous ESTA, which was valid at the time). Never overstayed anywhere.

I have just become a Canadian Permanent Resident in the past few months (but have lived here since Late 2019), so I am not sure how this will impact the "significant ties" thing.

In Canada I Have

- My common law partner
- Tax Returns / Payslips
- Employment contract since August 2021 (Canadian subsidiary of a company I own in France. No physical presence / online business.)
- Bank accounts / Credit cards etc
- Utility bills (but no lease agreement, partner owns house)
- Mortgage pre approval for buying a house with my partner
- Flight school logs / exams (I am learning to fly a plane as a hobby)

In France I Have

- All other family (brother, parents, grandparents)
- Two businesses I own (both are online, they have no physical
  presence)

Will my change to being a Canadian Permanent Resident adversely impact my chances of getting a US tourist visa?

Comment: Welcome Mr Man. This isn't a discussion site, and it seeks questions with declarative answers. Your question will generate only opinion, and is off-topic. It's likely to be closed. Take the site [Tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how the site works.

Comment: I recommend editing your question to ask if your recent change to being a Canadian PR will make any difference to your getting a visa. That's an objective question that will probably be on topic.

Comment: Also, will this be your first time in the US following your visit to a prohibited country?

Comment: @DJClayworth Changed the question, thanks. Yes it will be the first time.

Answer (score 12):

Becoming a Canadian Permanent Resident is very unlikely to have a negative impact on your chances of getting a US Visa.

Going through the process of becoming a Canadian PR shows a lack of desire to immigrate to the US. Showing proof of residence and employment in Canada are almost certainly going to be enough to convince a US immigration official that you do not intend to immigrate to the US. The short duration won't be a problem, any more than a recent move within France would have been. Taking a vacation in the US is something millions of Canadian residents do every year.

The only question mark is really your visit to the prohibited country. They will want to be sure it was not part of a plan to attack the US, or something else detrimental. As long as you have a good reason for doing so it's unlikely to be a problem (I know plenty of people in that situation who were given long term visas.)